# node.js better way to add controller files for performance optimizing

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express

In my express mvc project , i added all controllers files to app.js with this code;

```
// dynamically include routes (Controller)
fs.readdirSync('./controllers').forEach(function(file) {
  if (file.substr(-3) == '.js') {
    route = require('./controllers/' + file);
    route.controller(app);
  }
});
```

fasterMoreover , i can add this controllers as modules one by one.

```
var single = require('./controllers/con-single');
app.get('/:slug, function(req, res) {
    single.getContent(req,res);
});
```

Which way is faster ?

Comment: What does 'best' mean? faster? less likely to break? fit for some purpose? If they both work, then it's mostly up to you and your environment. Unless there is something very specific to solve for. I'm being pedantic because this could be answered with a lot of opinion, which will be very quickly deleted on here.

Comment: changed to faster , performance is most important thing for me .